go-duckdb package and duckdb extensions on windows (namely httpf)
I have a go project where I need to access and query some parquet files held in s3, using duckdb.
The package i am using is this one:
https://github.com/marcboeker/go-duckdb
I am on windows 10, and after some initial issues i managed to get the duckdb working.
However, the httpf extension for getting s3 files is not included in the duckdb lib.
When i do a simple code snippet like this:
import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/marcboeker/go-duckdb"
)

db, err := sql.Open("duckdb", "")
    defer db.Close()
    _, err = db.Exec("INSTALL s3; LOAD s3;")

I get the following error:
Failed to install/load s3 extension: HTTP Error: Failed to download extension "httpfs" at URL "http://extensions.duckdb.org/v1.1.3/windows_amd64_mingw/httpfs.duckdb_extension.gz" (HTTP 403)
Extension "httpfs" is an existing extension.
So, installing the extension fails, because the url is wrong, which is completely true.
There is no file at this url.
I did find other urls that work, for example: http://extensions.duckdb.org/v1.1.3/windows_amd64_rtools/httpfs.duckdb_extension.gz
I unziped it and now i get another error when running the code:
Failed to install/load s3 extension: Invalid Input Error: Failed to load 's3', The file was built for the platform 'windows_amd64_rtools', but we can only load extensions built for platform 'windows_amd64_mingw'.
exit status 1
Obviously i can not use another version, i need the version for windows_amd64_mingw, in my case v1.1.3.
Any ideas?
